# Java DOM XML editing - appending and removing elements very slow

Tags: java, dom

I have a method that's supposed to change lines to paths in my svg (xml) document, using a DOM Editor that was already running a few other methods on the file. However, with this new lineToPath() method I've run it a couple times on the size of file I'll need to edit (>63,000 lines need to change to paths) and it takes between 3 and 4 minutes to run.

```
public void lineToPath() {
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("line");
        System.out.println("nList length = " + nList.getLength());
        
        String x1, x2, y1, y2, draw;
        int len = nList.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            // we have to keep editing the 1st element, because the
            // previously-first element is removed from this list at
            // the end of the function
            Element line = (Element) nList.item(0);
            
            // turn x & y attributes of line into draw instructions
            // for the path
            x1 = (line.getAttribute("x1"));
            x2 = (line.getAttribute("x2"));
            y1 = (line.getAttribute("y1"));
            y2 = (line.getAttribute("y2"));
            draw = "M" + x1 + " " + y1 + ", L" + x2 + " " + y2;
            
            Element path = doc.createElement("path");
            path.setAttribute("d", draw);
            
            // copy over all other attributes except x & y values
            NamedNodeMap listAttrs = line.getAttributes();
            for (int j = 0; j < listAttrs.getLength(); j++) {
                Attr attr = (Attr) listAttrs.item(j);
                char attrFirstChar = attr.getNodeName().charAt(0);
                
                if (attrFirstChar != 'x' && attrFirstChar != 'y'){
                    //path.setAttributeNode(attr);
                    path.setAttribute(attr.getName(), attr.getValue());
                }
            }
            //System.out.println("Path " + i + " ready to write");
            
            // replace the line with our new path
            line.getParentNode().appendChild(path);
            line.getParentNode().removeChild(line);
            //System.out.println("***replaced line " + i + " with path");
        }
    }
```

When I comment out `line.getParentNode().appendChild(path);` and `line.getParentNode().removeChild(line);` - i.e. when I do all the work of making the new path but don't actually substitute the path in for the line - my runtime drops to 3 *seconds*.

I've tried collapsing both lines into a replaceChild() line instead, but that shoots my runtime over 6 minutes to edit this single document.

Is there any way to do this faster with the DOM editor?

[Also: I am somewhat new, so any other criticisms on my code layout or readability would be very appreciated]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found so far has been ignoring the DOM editor entirely. There didn't seem to be a way to use it without my runtime taking way too long.

Using a BufferedReader to get every line, performing lots of manual string searches and substring concatenations and string insertions in the line, then writing the new line out with a BufferedWriter achieved the same result with less than 5% of the runtime.